# CKEditor - Widget plugin: How to set focus into nested editable of widget?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ckeditor

I'm working with **editable widgets** in **CKEditor 4.4.0.**
I've created widget with one editable element in it and it works OK.

But I want to give user possibility **to edit editable part right after creation**.

What I've tried:

Get widget editable and if it is just created - call **.focus()** method **of this editable** on widget **ready event**:

```
widget.editables.content.focus();
```

What I've found - that it would work only if focus call is called **in defer**.

So basically **it works in all browsers except Chrome**.

In all browsers after `widget.editables.content.focus()` called focus is really placed into widget's editable, because `widget.focusedEditable` variable contains correct value.

But in Chrome `widget.focusedEditable` variable stays empty, even after `widget.editables.content.focus()` called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a sample is hard to tell, but I would check one thing - try to place selection in the nested editable. You can use [`range#moveToElementEditablePosition`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-moveToElementEditablePosition) to set range position in a correct place and then `selection.selectRanges( [ range ] )`:

```
nestedEditable.focus();

var range = editor.createRange();
range.moveToElementEditablePosition( nestedEditable );
editor.getSelection().selectRanges( [ range ] );
```

Focusing may not be enough because focus is not so tightly related to selection as it might seem to be. The Widget System consider nested editable focused when it contains selection. If you want to debug this more closely see:

- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/902757f1e0982e414845bd061fe144ca3ad992e3/plugins/widget/plugin.js#L2396-L2413 - `selectionChange` listener that updates states.
- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/902757f1e0982e414845bd061fe144ca3ad992e3/tests/plugins/widget/nestededitables.js#L740-L745 - some test as an example of the solution I proposed.